# Rsync echoes back changed file name but does not copy it

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rsync

This is my first time using rsync.  I studied the command line options and chose the ones that fit my situation.

I have two servers at different IP addresses.  Here's my command string:

```
rsync -avrtu -e ssh /var/www/html root@xxx.xx.xx.xxx:/var/www/html
```

where the x's represent the remote IP address.  I tested with one file with a new timestamp (but the file size is the same as before).  Putty echoed back the file name that had changed but it did not transfer it.

Here is what Putty echoed back:

```
sending incremental file list
html/abcde.htm

sent 12,919 bytes  received 397 bytes  1,401.68 bytes/sec
total size is 8,909,156 speedup is 669.06
```

What about my command line options (avrtu) causes the file to be recognized but not copied to the other server?

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.

Thanks for any help.  Like I said, this is my first time with rsync.

Comment: How did you determine that the file was not transfered?

Comment: The timestamp did not change.  I would expect to see an updated timestamp on the server, but the timestamp remained the same as before.

Comment: Note: rsync options -r and -t are unnecessary as they are already contained in -a.

Comment: If I remove those, would the file timestamp change, showing that the file was transferred?

Comment: It should not change the behaviour of the rsync command. These options are simply redundant. So, probably: no.

Answer (score 0):

The rsync command in Linux stands for remote sync, and it works very well to copy, backup and sync data from one server to remote server.

The option "a" is for archive the data which has included functionalities of recursive "r" and time "t", so if you use "-a" option then no need to use "r" and "t" options.

Use below command for the desired process:

```
rsync -avu -e ssh /var/www/html root@xxx.xx.xx.xxx:/var/www/html
```

And check your login user prompt also, either use root login on source system also or use sudo with command. check here [examples](https://linuxconcept.com/rsync-example-for-system-administrator/)